# Link colors are broken inside tabu environments

Tags: tables, hyperref, tabu

I have a table built with the `tabu` environment that doesn't display the correct color for the urls it contains, even if the link itself works (that is, it opens the web page in the browser).

However, as you can see from the example below, the links are displayed correctly in the `tabular` and `longtable` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu,tabularx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor={[rgb]{.5,.5,.5}}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
This link has the correct color: \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}.

\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
  an url in tabular & \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabu} spread 0pt {|r|l|}
  an url in tabu & \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{tabu}

\begin{longtable}{|r|l|}
  an url in longtable & \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt {|r|l|}
  an url in longtabu & \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So, is there a way to make the colors work inside `tabu` or do I have to switch to the other environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I recommend using `tabu`. However, the solution is simple: define the color by name.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable,tabu,tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=myurlcolor]{hyperref}

\definecolor{myurlcolor}{rgb}{.8,.1,.1}

\begin{document}
This link has the correct color: \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}.

\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
  an url in tabular & \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabu} spread 0pt {|r|l|}
  an url in tabu & \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{tabu}

\begin{longtable}{|r|l|}
  an url in longtable & \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtabu} spread 0pt {|r|l|}
  an url in longtabu & \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had tried using `\textcolor[rgb]{.5,.5,.5}{...}` but it didn't work either. Why does your solution work?

Comment: @PierPaolo No idea of what `tabu` is doing (and no desire of knowing). But apparently the optional argument was confusing the package.